# Roles required to use PersistKeysToAzureBlobStorage with AzureServiceTokenProvider

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-blob-storage

I want my application to be able to initialize the data protection key storage at startup.

But it will only work if I use the *Azure Storage Access Key* and not the MSI or Azure user in my Visual Studio (az login) that I expected. I have given the user and VM Scale Set the roles Owner, Contributor, Storage blob Data Contributor without success.

Is it a must to use SAS or the Access Key in order for the blob to be created automatically?

> **Error when using the token provider (MSI, az login)**
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Internal.DataProtectionHostedService:
>   Information: Key ring failed to load during application startup.
>
> > Request Information
> >     StatusMessage:The specified resource does not exist.
> >     ErrorCode:ResourceNotFound
> >     ErrorMessage:The specified resource does not exist.

```
public void ConfigureServices( IServiceCollection services )
{
   var accessKey = "ddBU/...==";
   var blobUri   = new Uri( $"https://mystorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/keys.xml" );

   var tp    = new Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication.AzureServiceTokenProvider();
   var token = tp.GetAccessTokenAsync( $"https://mystorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/" ).Result;

   // OK - creates and updates blob when neccessary
   var sc = new Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Auth.StorageCredentials( "mystorageaccount", accessKey );

   // NOK - can only read the blob
   //sc = new Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Auth.StorageCredentials( token );

   var cbb = new Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlockBlob( blobUri, sc );

   services.AddDataProtection()           
           .PersistKeysToAzureBlobStorage( cbb )
           .SetApplicationName( "MyFrontends" );

}
```

Comment: That's weird, Storage Blob Data Contributor should allow writing blobs :/

Comment: @juunas I thought so too, can you verify if it works for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The role "**Storage blob Data Contributor**" does allow *PersistKeysToAzureBlobStorage()* to create and maintain the key in the Azure Storage Account.

I must have made a mistake while testing, maybe I did not wait long enough after applying the role or maybe I had not created the target container.